# Adding an ID to the child of an element

Tags: javascript

I have some HTML code that I am unable to edit without using javascript. The DIV I am trying to access is the child of another that has an ID:

```
<div id="contentcolumn">
    <div class ="content content_gray"></div>
    <div class ="forum_tabs"</div>
</div>
```

The DIV I am trying to access is the one with the class of `"content content_gray"`. I do not want to access it using the class because other elements have this class. I must access it by access the first-child of the DIV with the ID of "contentcolumn".

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: So what's your question? Go ahead and do it.

Comment: Really badly asked question, for future reference. You shouldn't be expecting the community to work on your behalf when you appear to have not even researched and formulated your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I must access it by access the first-child of the DIV with the ID of "contentcolumn".

You mean like this?

```
var elm = document.getElementById("contentcolumn").firstElementChild;
```

You've said it's the first child, so I didn't bother to check `className`, but of course you can if you like. You'd add that check by doing:

```
if (elm.className.match(/\bcontent\b/) && elm.className.match(\bcontent_gray\b)) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that not all browsers have `firstElementChild`. (I don't recall for sure whether IE8 does, for instance.) For those that don't, a simple loop does it (and works even on those that have it):

```
var elm = document.getElementById("contentcolumn").firstChild;
while (elm && elm.nodeType !== 1) {
    elm = elm.nextSibling;
}
```

To you could have a little utility library you use:

```
function firstElementChild(parent) {
    var node = parent && parent.firstElementChild;
    if (!node && parent) {
        node = parent.firstChild;
        while (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

---

You asked below how to set the element's `id` once you have the element. That part's easy:

```
elm.id = "value";
```

Comment: no im not using jQuery. But can you also include your answer how to set the child elements ID?

Comment: @TommyCoffee: Oh, that part's easy: `elm.id = "value";` :-)

Answer (score 0):

check the element.className of each document.getElementById("contentcolumn").getElementsByTagName("div")

or else, jQuery("#id > .class") looks simpler to me